# Votes tab in profile loses reopen/close vote information, is different from /admin vote counts

Tags: bug, voting, profile-page, vote-count, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [profile page shows 6 reopen votes total while I have at least 25 successful ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/profile-page-shows-6-reopen-votes-total-while-i-have-at-least-25-successful-ones)

In [my profile on User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/7627/ben-brocka) I found it very odd I had only one reopen vote listed in the Votes tab (it's a personal tab so you can only view it on your own profile). I *know* I've cast more than that. Oddly the one reopen vote that's been cast is on a deleted question.

According to Shog9 I have 24 reopen votes on that site, all but one were "deleted". Not really sure what that means in this context, but clearly it matters as far as the votes tab is concerned. I now have zero reopen votes again. They're definitely being eaten after some period of time or due to some other effect.

On closer inspection the Votes tab also has a much lower amount of close votes than are reported in the /admin mod tool page on User Experience; /admin shows I have 251, the Votes tab reports only 126. Since I'm a mod the Votes tab shows votes on deleted questions, so I don't think that's the issue here.

I don't know why they're disappearing, but they are. Please make it so this tab shows all reopen votes cast. It's nice to be able to review posts that have been closed/reopened, or that I've voted on trying to *get* them closed/reopened.

Comment: @TimStone Shog9 said expired votes used to be deleted but they arent' supposed to. I've also cast more than 1 reopen vote since being a mod, so it's not expiration. I've probably closed more than 126 posts since being a mod too

Comment: @TimStone apparently yes, all votes it shows are mod actions in my case