# profile page shows 6 reopen votes total while I have at least 25 successful ones

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, vote-count, vote-to-reopen

My Programmers profile page shows 6 reopen votes total in votes->reopen sub tab ([dev team only link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=votes&sort=reopen)) while per my recollection I have substantially more than that.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PspA4.png]

[Review stats](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats) say I have 67 reopen actions (not all of these are votes), and this doesn't even take into account votes cast out of review queue. [According to Data Explorer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7518593#7518593) there were at least 25 successful reopen votes.

Are these 6 **really** all of my reopen votes? If yes - why my memory, review stats and Data Explorer say otherwise?

- For the record, here is an **[example question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/180125/31260)** that somehow failed to make it into the list shown at screen shot above, despite the fact that [its revisions history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/180125/revisions) says right after Rev 3:

> **Post Reopened** by [gnat](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat), ...

---

<sub>I also checked numbers shown in other sub-tabs: "closure", "downvote", "upvote", "all" - all of these appear **way lower** than I would expect. For downvotes and closures I could possibly think this could be [due to deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144757/165773), but it is really hard to imagine few hundreds **upvoted** and about 20 **successfully reopened** posts to disappear.</sub>

Comment: I think this is a dupe (haven't found it yet). This page only shows the votes you cast directly, not actions taken from /review. So you've voted to reopen 6 times *from the actual question page*.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of this, but could be the same cause: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160492/167443

Comment: @Jim I am asking about stats shown to me my own, private votes tab, not about review activity tab which is intentionally public by design

Comment: 67 reviews is not the same thing as 67 reopen votes. 'Leave closed' counts as a review, not as a vote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters agree (corrected the question), but SEDE says I've got at least 25 **successful reopens**

Comment: Perhaps questions since closed again or deleted are not listed?

Comment: I know that the votes list does not include deleted posts, but I'm not aware of it excluding anything else.

Comment: @gnat What I'm getting at is that what that page shows is only posts you've acted on directly, and ignores all actions taken through the review queue. So if you open a question from the home page and use the close/reopen link below it, that would show up, but if you went to the review queue and clicked the close/reopen button, that would not.

Comment: @Jim I see thanks. If this is indeed so, that would be one of the funniest er "features" I've seen at SE. Except for, maybe, [CW attribution algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130820/165773 "strictly Klingonian") :)

Comment: @Jim: That only applies to the review history. Actions you take outside of review don't get tracked in your review history. Actions you take inside review *do* get tracked in any other histories they apply to. Those votes would still show up.

Comment: @gnat In regards to why SEDE says you only have 25 reopen votes, [SEDE only shows votes that haven't yet expired](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124716/158605), so you only have 25 reopen votes that haven't expired at this time. I actually have a feature-request on MSO to [show all successful votes in SEDE regardless of if they've expired or not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160981/158605), but no responses yet.

Comment: @gnat As for how many successful reopen votes you actually have, you can use the PostHistory table to find that out. According to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/91391/gnats-successful-reopen-votes), you have 28 successful reopen votes. I was messing around with PostHistory a few days ago, and also have a query saved to find [the top Reopen Voters for a site](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/90852/top-reopen-voters)

Comment: thanks @Rachel - by the way **"show all successful votes in SEDE regardless of if they've expired or not"** reads better than current title, did you consider editing it?

Comment: @Rachel while I have your attention note that 3 of top 5 in your list are moderators and that their binding vote cuts anyone else chance to add a vote to their stats. Not that I complain (rather opposite, I like that mods develop a taste in _reopen racket_), merely pointing that your stats data may be not perfectly balanced

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in the user page's votes tab - we should be showing any close, reopen, delete, and undelete votes that a user has made, regardless of the deletion state of those votes.

Comment: thanks! is there a plan to fix this bug?

Comment: Yes, our usual capricious plan :) I'll check something in tonight for it.  Build will be in the next 24 hours.

Comment: woo-hoo you plan works! sub-tab now shows 45 total / 28 successful reopen votes, this feels about right to me. Thank you thank you thank you. I also checked close votes count, it looks more realistic than before

Comment: ...I'd consider this [meta-tag:status-completed] and retag accordingly

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this is [actually a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140406/votes-tab-in-profile-loses-reopen-close-vote-information-is-different-from-adm), but I'll answer the support side of it here since I can't address the behaviour directly.

You *have* cast more reopen votes (of which at least 25 have been successful), but only those six votes haven't yet [*expired*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags/97581#97581) (although presumably your vote on [lightweight document indexing to handle less than 250k potential records](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181296/lightweight-document-indexing-to-handle-less-than-250k-potential-records) will expire soon), and there's no consideration given to whether the other votes were involved in a successful reopen/close action when excluding them from the view.

It's my understanding that the votes are still retained after expiration, so provided that's the case the query used to pull the lists could be reworked to show all non-expired or successful votes (as performance considerations allow).

Comment: This seems plausible. *Why* it works this way, I have no clue.

Comment: interesting... [rev history for 'lightweight' question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/165364/revisions) shows reopen was cast **no later than Oct 16 and it's in the list**, but in the [example given in my question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/180125/revisions) it was cast much later, **on Dec 21 - and it's not listed**. I somehow fail to fit the expiration in there

Comment: @Shog9 Well, unless there's enough additional information in the live data, checking this is rather a pain...so "because easy" would be my guess, heh.

Comment: @gnat The first question doesn't have a sufficient number of views for votes to start expiring, whereas your example question does (views > 100)

Comment: @TimStone I see, now that makes some sense. Now if I only could figure what happened to few hundreds missing upvotes...

Comment: @gnat: As stated in the comments above, votes on deleted posts are not shown to you in your votes tab.

Comment: @animuson I know, see note at the bottom of my question in small font :)