# Delete votes tab in profile doesn't show votes on deleted posts (ironically)

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, moderator-tools, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

The [Delete votes part of my profile (dev only link)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/42/rarity?tab=votes&sort=deletion) appears to only show posts I've voted to delete, but weren't deleted. For instance on Workplace it shows 5 posts, on UX it shows 3 posts. I have, as a mod, deleted...more than 8 posts. I can confirm this from the /admin dashboard which has a nice list of all my delete votes.

This is true for undelete votes too; undelete votes will only show undeleted posts. Active undelete votes on deleted questions won't show up in the votes tab. As a non-mod that makes it nearly impossible to track your undelete votes until the post is undeleted. (And as a mod it seems weird I can't see them either way, after all I can even *search* for deleted posts)

Shouldn't delete votes track deleted posts too? It could at least show the amount of posts I've voted to delete, even if we don't want to show people deleted posts. But I'll note that as both a Mod Tools user on one site and a current mod on the other, I still don't see the posts I've voted to delete that stayed deleted. I think all votes should be listed, regardless of deletion status. Barring that, at least give the proper counts at the top, even if only listing the undeleted ones.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't this undelete vote listed in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165396)

Comment: The votes tab doesn't show votes on deleted posts (even for the delete and undelete tabs). Very ironic. (You should change this into a feature request.)

Comment: @animuson I'm not sure it's intended, wouldn't be the first time that page was missing votes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162044/profile-page-shows-6-reopen-votes-total-while-i-have-at-least-25-successful-ones

Comment: @BenBrocka: It is definitely intended. Just everyone is always too lazy to post a real feature request to change it. *whistles innocently*

Comment: @animuson fine fine. Playing Bug or Feature can be very tricky on MSO

Comment: Oh, yeah, I meant to come back to "Why isn't this undelete vote listed?" Do you mind expanding this request to "Delete/undelete votes should link to post regardless of that post's status", Ben, or would you prefer I make mine about undelete votes into a separate request?

Comment: @JoshCaswell added in undelete votes, since it's basically the same problem

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm gonna VTC mine as a dupe of this now.