# Votes casts do not match

Tags: support, voting

When looking at my total votes in the 'votes' tab (not the summary) on my profile on SO I saw that I had a total of 236 Votes Cast. However when I look at my badge progress of the Civic Duty badge it says that I votes 292 times:

[image]

[image]

Is there any logical reason for the count difference?

Comment: Maybe deleted questions make the difference.

Comment: @qben That would indeed be a very logical explanation but it would be great if someone could confirm this.

Comment: It is showing "293 Votes Cast" currently.

Comment: @hjpotter92 My badge progress is at 293 now, but on my profile it still says "237 Votes Cast".

Comment: I just opened your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2134785/daanvn) and it states "294 Votes cast"

Comment: For everyone saying they see the higher number: compare the votes cast in your own profile summary with the votes cast in the votes tab. There should be a difference. (The votes tab is only visible in your own profile.)

Comment: My summary says 1586 vs 2139 but I see the difference is that the larger figure includes "votes for closure" and "votes for reopen" while the smaller figure is up/down only.

Comment: @RogerRowland Then compare your upvotes and downvotes: I have 1266 vs. 1232 up and 355 vs. 108 down on meta. I'm pretty sure that is due to deleted posts.

Comment: @RalZarek yes I can see similar, a much smaller difference though so I guess the big difference on the civic duty badge is due to close/reopen votes cast on the review queue(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the votes tab in your profile does not include votes on since-deleted posts. This is particularly confusing on the delete votes tab, but you can always [support the request to change that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166851/delete-votes-tab-in-profile-doesnt-show-votes-on-deleted-posts-ironically).

Note that the voting section on the summary tab of your profile *does* factor in up/down votes on deleted content, so those numbers should generally be consistent with what you see in the badge progress bar.