# Don't show Delete/Undelete votes of my own posts

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, vote-to-delete

Most of the entries of the delete vote tab in my profile

```
Open Profile -> Votes -> deletion/undelete
```

show my own posts I deleted/undeleted. I am not interested in them. Can we have a checkbox at the botton to filter these?

Like

```
x  Show my own posts
```

BTW this [looks like a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166851/delete-votes-tab-in-profile-doesnt-show-votes-on-deleted-posts-ironically), since I can hardly find entries that are not my posts.

Comment: Filtering by "All/only my own/only others" would be useful for most tabs on the profile page.